# Altair area plot with color determined by sign

Tags: altair

I would like to make a plot in which I shade the area between two curves and the color depends on which curve is higher (so, for example, the area between the curves is green if "curve 1" is above "curve 2" and red if "curve 1" is below "curve 2"). The following plot is my best effort at making such a plot. The result is close to what I want, but has the problem that it connects regions with the same sign when I do not want this. (The most conspicuous example is the green region connecting "x~0.6" to "x~1.1".) Is there a better way to make such a plot?

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.linspace(0, 2, 100),
})
df['y1'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df.x)
df['y2'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df.x)
df['c'] = (df.y1 > df.y2).apply(lambda b: 'darkseagreen' if b else 'indianred')

base_chart = alt.Chart(df, width=1.618 * 400, height=400)
l1 = base_chart.mark_line(stroke='green', strokeWidth=4).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y=alt.Y('y1:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='y')),
)
l2 = base_chart.mark_line(stroke='red', strokeWidth=4).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y2:Q',
)
a = base_chart.mark_area().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y1:Q',
    y2='y2:Q',
    fill=alt.Color('c:N', scale=None),
)
alt.layer(a, l1, l2)
```

[image: Altair area plot with color determined by sign]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I could use `impute` to prevent the unwanted lines between regions from being drawn.

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.linspace(0, 2, 100),
})
df['y1'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df.x)
df['y2'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df.x)
df['c'] = (df.y1 > df.y2).apply(lambda b: 'darkseagreen' if b else 'indianred')

base_chart = alt.Chart(df, width=1.618 * 400, height=400)
l1 = base_chart.mark_line(stroke='green', strokeWidth=4).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y=alt.Y('y1:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='y')),
)
l2 = base_chart.mark_line(stroke='red', strokeWidth=4).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y2:Q',
)
a = base_chart.mark_area().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y=alt.Y('y1:Q', impute={'value': None}),
    y2='y2:Q',
    fill=alt.Color('c:N', scale=None),
)
alt.layer(a, l1, l2)
```

[image: Area Plot]